# Выключатель для участка кода на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы только после нажатия на `qpushbutton_2` моя программа работала, я пытался это сделать с помощью чётных и нечётных чисел. При нажатии на кнопку переменная `k` меняла своё значение на `k+1`, то есть чётное или нечётное, как вкл и выкл, но у меня просто не работало, ошибок не было. Попробовал через длину массива, чтобы не использовать глобальные переменные, может это мешало, но нет, даже так не работает, однако я выводил в консоль результат работы функции `on` и всё хорошо, значит проблема в самом цикле, как мне кажется, но я не знаю какая. Я юзал циклы `while` и `if`, но ничего не выходит. Да, может лучше работать через Tkinter, но я совсем зелёный. Я уже целый день ищу ответ и ничего. Заранее извиняюсь за, может, глупый вопрос и плохое оформление, просто я задаю вопрос первый раз, да и программирую на пайтоне совсем чуть-чуть.

```
import sys

import pyowm

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from ui import Ui_Weather

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Weather()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

k = [1]

def on():
    k.append(1)
    print(k)

ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(on)

if len(k) % 2 == 0:
    ui.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(False)
    ui.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText("Enter a place")
    def set_place():
        try:
            place = str(ui.lineEdit_4.text())
            owm = pyowm.OWM('d35e6b2922b666c330687c8f90816531', language = 'en')
            observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
            w = observation.get_weather()   
            temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
            ui.lineEdit_4.clear()
            ui.lineEdit.setText(str(int(temp)) + " °C")
            ui.lineEdit_2.setText("In " + str(place) + " is " + str(w.get_detailed_status()) + " now.")
            if temp < -10:
                ui.lineEdit_3.setText("It's very cold now")
            elif temp < 0:
                ui.lineEdit_3.setText("It's cold now")
            elif temp < 13:
                ui.lineEdit_3.setText("It's not very warm now")
            elif temp < 23:
                ui.lineEdit_3.setText("The temperature is perfect now")
            elif temp < 30:
                ui.lineEdit_3.setText("It's very warm now")
            elif temp > 30:
                ui.lineEdit_3.setText("It's too hot to stay outside")
        except: 
            ui.lineEdit_4.setText("Error, please try again.")
            ui.lineEdit_3.clear()
            ui.lineEdit_2.clear()
            ui.lineEdit.clear()




    ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(set_place)

else:
    ui.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
    ui.lineEdit.clear()
    ui.lineEdit_2.clear()
    ui.lineEdit_3.clear()
    ui.lineEdit_4.clear()



sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно вас понимаю, 
но попробуйте поменять импорт и нажать кнопку.

```
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets           #  PySide2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets              #  PyQt5

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.on_off = False

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Начать работу")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)   

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.on_off = not self.on_off
        if self.on_off:    
            print("Пошел процесс")
            self.pushButton_2.setText("ОСТАНОВИТЬ работу")
        if not self.on_off:
            self.pushButton_2.setText("Начать работу")
            print("Процесс остановлен")


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapp = MainWindow()
    mainapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import pyowm
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot, Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout
import pyowm


class CollectData(QThread):
    send = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.place = ""

    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        owm = pyowm.OWM('d35e6b2922b666c330687c8f90816531', language='ru')
        observation = owm.weather_at_place(self.place)
        temperature = observation.get_weather().get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
        self.send.emit(str(temperature))

    def setPlace(self, place):
        print(place)
        if place == "":
            self.place = "Москва"
        else:
            self.place = place


class Weather(QWidget, ):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Погодный информер")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.place_name = QLineEdit(self)
        self.place_name.setPlaceholderText("Введите название города");

        self.info = QLabel(self)
        self.info.setText("Температура:")

        grid.addWidget(self.place_name, 0, 0, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.info, 1, 0, 1, 0)

        self.collect_data = CollectData()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        print(key)
        if key == 16777220:
            print(self.place_name.text())
            self.collect_data.setPlace(self.place_name.text())
            self.collect_data.start()
            self.collect_data.send.connect(self.process_data)


    def process_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        self.info.setText("Температура: {0}".format(data))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    weather = Weather()
    weather.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```